# Azure Environment detection from VM running CentOS

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

We have a requirement where from a CentOS instance we need to understand if the given VM is running on Azure or Hyper-V. We have tried using using dmidecode to see if their is any information that would help providing this information. Unfortunately the dmidecode for both are identical and the only difference seems to be UUID and Serial No. Any suggestions on alternatives to find this information would be welcome.
Thanks & Regards - Mahesh

Answer (score 0):

From Azure VM the Azure VM metadata endpoint is accessible and curl to that endpoint will respond with VM metadata json  `curl -H Metadata:true --noproxy "*" "http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance?api-version=2020-09-01"` as described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/instance-metadata-service . This endpoint will not be accessible if VM is not an Azure VM, and curl will respond with error. This can be used to distinguish if VM is an Azure VM or not

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Mani. We did evaluate this approach. This assumes network connectivity would be up at the time Azure VM evaluation is being done. In our scenario that might not be true and we might have to identify even when there is no network connectivity. Thanks & Regards